# Cannot shutdown unless I use tty

Tags: shutdown, lightdm, 13.04

On my computer, I noticed a quirk where I cannot shutdown unless I enter tty or logout then shutdown from the users screen.  Clicking on the shutdown button either logs me out or causes lightdm to crash (error mentions something about broken pipe, I'm unsure though).

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 (iso 4-23-13) 32-bit.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open a Terminal and run the following command :

```
unity  - - reset 

dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

Log out of your desktop session and back into Unity for changes to take effect.

Step 2

To refresh your Unity launcher with the default set of icons, run the following in a Terminal:

```
unity --reset-icons
```

This command will “restart” Unity immediately, running from the Terminal. Closing the Terminal will also ‘close’ Unity, so it’s best to log out and back in after running this command.

Hope this might work indirectly.

Comment: The command `unity --reset-icons` put back a bunch of junk icons into my dash, and still did not help the no-shutdown problem.